# Android studio connects to the mobile phone via USB ,but crashes when running the APP

Tags: android, crash, usb

I'm trying to deploy yolov8 on android phone.I followed this instructable  [https://medium.com/@gary.tsai.advantest/top-tutorials-for-deploying-custom-yolov8-on-android-%EF%B8%8F-dd6746afc1e6](https://stackoverflow.com)
I use Android studio connects to the mobile phone via USB ,but crashes when running the APP, and there is no error message ,it shows"launch succeed".Please help me to solve this!

This is the logcast

```
--------- beginning of crash
2023-08-17 22:02:25.709 7752-7785/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x100 in tid 7785 (ImageReader-640), pid 7752 (cent.yolov8ncnn)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.721 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:1_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84e9090 priv:0xb400007b085dfb18
2023-08-17 22:02:25.732 1240-2274/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:1_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:1 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.733 1585-7798/? E/Camera3-Stream: [VSync] getBuffer: Stream 0: wait for max dequeued buffer exceeds 30000us (38733)us
2023-08-17 22:02:25.737 1240-31326/? E/CHIUSECASE: [ERROR  ] chxadvancedcamerausecase.cpp:6617 SetPriorityMetadata() [3rd party DBG][ISO] ERROR, Check, please(37)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.737 1240-31326/? W/CHIUSECASE: [WARN   ] chifeature2usecaserequestobject.cpp:456 Initialize() pUsecaseSettings is NULL!!
2023-08-17 22:02:25.757 7884-7884/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstoneProto
2023-08-17 22:02:25.757 746-746/? I/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 7785
2023-08-17 22:02:25.758 7884-7884/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 7752 (target tid = 7785)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.761 1240-2273/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:2_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84c97b0 priv:0xb400007b085fa298
2023-08-17 22:02:25.772 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:2_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:2 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.773 1585-7798/? E/Camera3-Stream: [VSync] getBuffer: Stream 0: wait for max dequeued buffer exceeds 30000us (35623)us
2023-08-17 22:02:25.777 1506-5627/? D/MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.tencent.yolov8ncnn    className : com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.MainActivity
2023-08-17 22:02:25.807 1240-2273/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:3_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84c0130 priv:0xb400007b085f3458
2023-08-17 22:02:25.819 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:3_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:3 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.847 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:4_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84b1bf0 priv:0xb400007b085c82d8
2023-08-17 22:02:25.858 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:4_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:4 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.870 1506-6603/? D/SGM:GameManager: identifyForegroundApp. com.tencent.yolov8ncnn, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
2023-08-17 22:02:25.870 1506-6603/? D/SGM:PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.tencent.yolov8ncnn
2023-08-17 22:02:25.870 20560-20593/? I/PolicyManager: [#CMH#] Is foreground game app: false
2023-08-17 22:02:25.889 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:5_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84c35b0 priv:0xb400007b086312d8
2023-08-17 22:02:25.905 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:5_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:5 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.913 1225-7872/? I/HYPER-HAL: [ResourceManager.cpp]removeResource(): [CPUMinFreq] RemoveResource Request ID : 1162068
2023-08-17 22:02:25.913 1225-7872/? I/HYPER-HAL: [RequestManager.cpp]releaseLocked(): Released ID : 1162068
2023-08-17 22:02:25.926 7884-7884/? E/unwind: Failed to initialize DEX file support: dlopen failed: library "libdexfile.so" not found
2023-08-17 22:02:25.930 1240-2272/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:6_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84ba7f0 priv:0xb400007b085f8698
2023-08-17 22:02:25.945 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:6_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:6 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.972 1240-2272/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:7_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84dda90 priv:0xb400007b08635e18
2023-08-17 22:02:25.987 1240-2273/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:7_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:7 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:25.996 1225-7747/? I/HYPER-HAL: [ResourceManager.cpp]removeResource(): [CPULittleMinFreq] RemoveResource Request ID : 1188146
2023-08-17 22:02:25.996 5368-5368/? I/ResourceOverlayService_0: waitAndQuit called
2023-08-17 22:02:25.997 5368-5368/? I/ResourceOverlayService_0: activity user id 0 process id 0
2023-08-17 22:02:25.998 1225-7747/? I/HYPER-HAL: [ResourceManager.cpp]removeResource(): [CPUMinFreq] RemoveResource Request ID : 1188146
2023-08-17 22:02:25.998 1225-7747/? I/HYPER-HAL: [RequestManager.cpp]releaseLocked(): Released ID : 1188146
2023-08-17 22:02:26.014 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:8_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84db330 priv:0xb400007b085de618
2023-08-17 22:02:26.029 1240-2272/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:8_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:8 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.056 1240-2271/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5972 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:9_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:0 with metadata:0xb400007ad84c0f30 priv:0xb400007b08634058
2023-08-17 22:02:26.072 1240-2274/? I/CHIUSECASE: [CONFIG ] chifeature2base.cpp:5982 ProcessResult() FRO-URO:9_RealtimeFG:RealTime_0 Result from Request:9 with 1 buffer(s)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.072 1585-1856/? I/Camera3-Status: markComponent: Component 2 is now idle - streamId = 0, format = 0x23(YUV_420_888), width = 640, height = 480, option = 0x0, type = OUTPUT
2023-08-17 22:02:26.072 1585-1856/? I/Camera3-IOStreamBase: FpsStats: stream 0, requested=10, received=10, valid=10, invalid=0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.072 1585-1856/? I/Camera3-Status: markComponent: Component 0 is now idle - InflightRequests
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a52sxqzt/a52sxq:13/TP1A.220624.014/A528BZTU2EWC1:user/release-keys'
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '4'
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Processor: '7'
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2023-08-17 22:02:25.770107992+0800
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Process uptime: 2s
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.tencent.yolov8ncnn
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: pid: 7752, tid: 7785, name: ImageReader-640  >>> com.tencent.yolov8ncnn <<<
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10340
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x00000100
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000100  r1  00000000  r2  00000000  r3  00000000
2023-08-17 22:02:26.075 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:     r4  bc821244  r5  00000140  r6  00000007  r7  bbfbb798
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:     r8  bbfbba50  r9  ece5de38  r10 e866e8e0  r11 00000000
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:     ip  eeadb61d  sp  bbfbb5f8  lr  bc1383ab  pc  bc138402
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000ac402  /data/app/~~TV6X8-9gOav5QbgtfFd7SA==/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn-lkMM_fesnuf9RRXXhhFYCg==/base.apk!libyolov8ncnn.so (BuildId: a63bc917a9d4a059f8b1d118b5a912554e35cf0d)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000abd87  /data/app/~~TV6X8-9gOav5QbgtfFd7SA==/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn-lkMM_fesnuf9RRXXhhFYCg==/base.apk!libyolov8ncnn.so (Yolo::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::__ndk1::vector<Object, std::__ndk1::allocator<Object> >&, float, float)+566) (BuildId: a63bc917a9d4a059f8b1d118b5a912554e35cf0d)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000aa4a9  /data/app/~~TV6X8-9gOav5QbgtfFd7SA==/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn-lkMM_fesnuf9RRXXhhFYCg==/base.apk!libyolov8ncnn.so (MyNdkCamera::on_image_render(cv::Mat&) const+84) (BuildId: a63bc917a9d4a059f8b1d118b5a912554e35cf0d)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 000b1fed  /data/app/~~TV6X8-9gOav5QbgtfFd7SA==/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn-lkMM_fesnuf9RRXXhhFYCg==/base.apk!libyolov8ncnn.so (NdkCameraWindow::on_image(unsigned char const*, int, int) const+1632) (BuildId: a63bc917a9d4a059f8b1d118b5a912554e35cf0d)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000b11a5  /data/app/~~TV6X8-9gOav5QbgtfFd7SA==/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn-lkMM_fesnuf9RRXXhhFYCg==/base.apk!libyolov8ncnn.so (BuildId: a63bc917a9d4a059f8b1d118b5a912554e35cf0d)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0001f747  /system/lib/libmediandk.so (AImageReader::CallbackHandler::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+350) (BuildId: 6b00df3d998888ce6e4ee6de47bbe28a)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00014213  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+50) (BuildId: e238de823b115da169c13cc8fd7ae064)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000185e3  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+138) (BuildId: e238de823b115da169c13cc8fd7ae064)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00014ffd  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+580) (BuildId: e238de823b115da169c13cc8fd7ae064)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 0000d789  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+264) (BuildId: b2621212a92b1edc2019361ac138390b)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 0008b995  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+84) (BuildId: f4100e8c39984e41d110f5690e993601)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00083f9f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40) (BuildId: 74fd868d848748f0cdd92430597d038a)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.076 7884-7884/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 0003adad  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: 74fd868d848748f0cdd92430597d038a)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.086 5273-5273/? I/ViewRootImpl@bce2ce2[StatusBar]: performTraversals params={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL sim={adjust=pan} layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=81000008
      pfl=13001000
      bhv=DEFAULT
      paramsForRotation=
      rot[0]={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[1]={(0,0)(fillx68) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[2]={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[3]={(0,0)(fillx68) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} naviIconColor=0}
2023-08-17 22:02:26.087 5273-5273/? I/ViewRootImpl@bce2ce2[StatusBar]: performTraversals mFirst=false windowShouldResize=false viewVisibilityChanged=false mForceNextWindowRelayout=false params={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL sim={adjust=pan} layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=81000008
      pfl=13001000
      bhv=DEFAULT
      paramsForRotation=
      rot[0]={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[1]={(0,0)(fillx68) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[2]={(0,0)(fillx88) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} 
      rot[3]={(0,0)(fillx68) gr=TOP CENTER_VERTICAL layoutInDisplayCutoutMode=always ty=STATUS_BAR fmt=TRANSLUCENT
      fl=80000008
      pfl=11000000
      bhv=DEFAULT naviIconColor=0} naviIconColor=0}
2023-08-17 22:02:26.088 1506-6603/? I/WindowManager: Cancelling animation restarting=true, leash=Surface(name=Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation)/@0x1fb03df
2023-08-17 22:02:26.088 1506-6603/? I/WindowManager: Reparenting to original parent: Surface(name=WindowToken{aee4dd3 type=2000 android.os.BinderProxy@c81600d})/@0x4e7aa8d, destroy=false, surface=Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24
2023-08-17 22:02:26.088 1506-6603/? I/WindowManager: Reparenting to leash, surface=Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24, leashParent=Surface(name=WindowToken{aee4dd3 type=2000 android.os.BinderProxy@c81600d})/@0x4e7aa8d
2023-08-17 22:02:26.088 1288-1393/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14753 createSurf, flag=24000, Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation#14753
2023-08-17 22:02:26.089 1506-6603/? D/WindowManager: makeSurface duration=0 leash=Surface(name=Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation)/@0x594483a
2023-08-17 22:02:26.091 5273-5273/? I/ViewRootImpl@bce2ce2[StatusBar]: updateBlastSurfaceIfNeeded mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400007ac0e1fb50 isSameSurfaceControl=true
2023-08-17 22:02:26.092 5273-5273/? I/BLASTBufferQueue: update, w= 1080 h= 88 mName = ViewRootImpl@bce2ce2[StatusBar] mNativeObject= 0xb400007ac0e1fb50 sc.mNativeObject= 0xb400007a50ff48c0 format= -3 caller= android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateBlastSurfaceIfNeeded:2898 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9847 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3884 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:3116 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:10885 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1301 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.092 5273-5273/? I/ViewRootImpl@bce2ce2[StatusBar]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,88) new=(0,0,1080,88) req=(1080,88)0 dur=4 res=0x0 s={true 0xb400007b50e2ca50} ch=false seqId=5
2023-08-17 22:02:26.094 1506-7892/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_native_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
2023-08-17 22:02:26.094 746-746/? E/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: tombstone_15
2023-08-17 22:02:26.095 1506-7891/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:722 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:598 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:10385 com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run:88 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.095 1506-7891/? W/ActivityManager: crash : com.tencent.yolov8ncnn,10340
2023-08-17 22:02:26.096 1506-7891/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/.MainActivity
2023-08-17 22:02:26.097 1506-7891/? W/WindowManager: Prepare app transition: mNextAppTransitionRequests=[TRANSIT_CLOSE], mNextAppTransitionFlags=TRANSIT_FLAG_KEYGUARD_GOING_AWAY_TO_LAUNCHER_WITH_IN_WINDOW_ANIMATIONS | TRANSIT_FLAG_APP_CRASHED, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:6470 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.requestTransitionAndLegacyPrepare:6486 com.android.server.wm.Task.finishTopCrashedActivityLocked:6747 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.lambda$finishTopCrashedActivities$19:2688 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.$r8$lambda$4nB35TzseTo6qyVD9NxDieoJN1Y:0 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.098 1506-2344/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_15 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.098 1506-2344/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE isTagEnabled=true flags=0x6
2023-08-17 22:02:26.098 1506-7891/? D/ActivityTaskManager: scheduleTopResumedActivityChanged, onTop=false r=ActivityRecord{242a004 u0 com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/.MainActivity} t5928 f}} caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.updateTopResumedActivityIfNeeded:2508 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.positionChildTaskAt:602 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.positionChildAt:537 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.positionChildAt:970 com.android.server.wm.Task.positionChildAt:3352 com.android.server.wm.Task.moveToFrontInner:6003 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.099 1088-1088/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1692280946.093:121961): auid=4294967295 uid=10340 gid=10340 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 pid=7752 comm="ImageReader-640" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" sig=11 res=1
2023-08-17 22:02:26.102 1506-7891/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application(0): ActivityRecord{1e27a49 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity} t5784}
2023-08-17 22:02:26.102 1288-1288/? I/Layer: id=14745 removedFromDrawingState Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation#14745 (183)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.102 1288-1288/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14745 Removed Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation#14745 (183)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.102 1288-1288/? I/Layer: id=14745 Destroyed Surface(name=75f9d10 StatusBar)/@0xb525f24 - animation-leash of insets_animation#14745
2023-08-17 22:02:26.104 1506-7891/? D/MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.tencent.yolov8ncnn, userId = 0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.104 1506-7891/? D/StatusBarManagerService: notifyRequestedSystemKey recent=false home=false
2023-08-17 22:02:26.104 1506-7891/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread: TaskStackListener.onTaskFocusChanged(), taskId=5928, focused=false
2023-08-17 22:02:26.104 1506-7891/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread: TaskStackListener.onTaskFocusChanged(), taskId=5784, focused=true
2023-08-17 22:02:26.104 1506-2344/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE_PROTO isTagEnabled=true flags=0x4
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-7891/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread:   sendRunningComponentFocus(), pkgName: com.sec.android.app.launcher, userId: 0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-2424/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread: onLooperPrepared(), msg: MSG_TASK_FOCUSED, pkgName: com.sec.android.app.launcher, userId: 0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-2424/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread: handleTaskFocused().
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-2424/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread: sendFocusOutConditionally() - mPrevNotiPkg: (unknown), userId: 0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-2424/? D/SGM:FgCheckThread:   handleTaskFocused(), pkgName: com.sec.android.app.launcher, userID:0 mResumedPkgMap does not containsKey.
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-7891/? W/WindowManager: Prepare app transition: mNextAppTransitionRequests=[TRANSIT_CLOSE, TRANSIT_CLOSE], mNextAppTransitionFlags=TRANSIT_FLAG_KEYGUARD_GOING_AWAY_TO_LAUNCHER_WITH_IN_WINDOW_ANIMATIONS | TRANSIT_FLAG_APP_CRASHED, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:6470 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:6461 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.finishIfPossible:4142 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.finishIfPossible:3957 com.android.server.wm.Task.finishTopCrashedActivityLocked:6748 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-7891/? D/RestrictionPolicy: isScreenCaptureEnabled : ret=true userId=0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.105 1506-7891/? D/RestrictionPolicy: isScreenCaptureEnabled : ret=true userId=0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.108 1288-1288/? I/Layer: id=14754 Destroyed Screenshot Parent#14754
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-7798/? E/Camera3-OutputStream: [VSync] getBufferLockedCommon: Stream 0: wait for dequeued buffer exceeds 30000us (339463)us
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-7798/? E/Camera3-OutputStream: getBufferLockedCommon: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1506-5325/? D/InputMethodManagerService: removeClient
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-7798/? E/CameraDeviceClient: notifyError: pid=7752, errorCode=3, errorStreamId=-1, frameNumber=10
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-7798/? E/CameraDeviceClient: notifyError: pid=7752, skipClientNotification=false
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-5858/? D/CameraService: CameraService::binderDied
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1506-5325/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=949
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1288-2461/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14747 Removed Bounds for - com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.MainActivity@0#14747 (182)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1585-5858/? I/CameraService: clearCamConnRef: ref=1
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1288-2461/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14748 Removed SurfaceView[com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.MainActivity]@0#14748 (182)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1288-2461/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14749 Removed SurfaceView[com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.MainActivity]@0(BLAST)#14749 (182)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.113 1288-1987/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=14750 Removed Background for SurfaceView[com.tencent.yolov8ncnn/com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.MainActivity]@0#14750 (182)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.114 1506-5325/? I/InputMethodBindingController: setCurrentMethodNotVisible: mVisibleBound=false, mHasConnection=true, caller = com.android.server.inputmethod.InputMethodManagerService.hideCurrentInputLocked:4339 com.android.server.inputmethod.InputMethodManagerService.removeClient:2824 com.android.server.inputmethod.InputMethodManagerService$ClientDeathRecipient.binderDied:680 android.os.IBinder$DeathRecipient.binderDied:323 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:781 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
2023-08-17 22:02:26.114 1136-1136/? I/Zygote: Process 7752 exited due to signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
2023-08-17 22:02:26.114 1585-5858/? I/CameraService: clearCamConnRef: service.camera.running set to 0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.114 1585-5858/? I/CameraService: evictClientIdByRemote: remove client from mActiveClientManager.
2023-08-17 22:02:26.114 1222-1222/? I/sensors-hal: activate:259, android.sensor.accelerometer/11 en=0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1222-1222/? I/sensors-hal: deactivate:306, disconnect qmi to disable sensor
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1222-1222/? I/sensors-hal: activate:270, android.sensor.accelerometer/11 en=0 completed
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? E/CameraDeviceClient: notifyError: pid=7752, errorCode=0, errorStreamId=-1, frameNumber=0
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? E/CameraDeviceClient: notifyError: pid=7752, skipClientNotification=false
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? E/CameraDeviceClient: Disconnect from CameraDeviceClient
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? D/CameraDeviceClient: disconnect:stop IT Policy checking thread
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? D/Camera2ClientBase: Camera 1: start to disconnect
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? D/Camera2ClientBase: Camera 1: serializationLock acquired
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? D/Camera2ClientBase: Camera 1: Shutting down
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? D/Camera2ClientBase: Camera 1: start to cacheDump
2023-08-17 22:02:26.115 1585-5858/? E/Camera2-FrameProcessorBase: removeListener:
```

I change the SDK version.